# fieldtype development advice

Tags: fieldtype

I began building a channel field form to enter all the data (as seen in the attached image), the form seems cumbersome and lengthy.

Now I am thinking about creating my own fieldtype, so I have more control over the layout. It will basically be its own form since it will contain so many fields within it.

There will be other fields in this channel field group.

Do you see any shortcomings to building a fieldtype that is essentially a form within itself?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built a fieldtype that may do what you want without your having to build one from scratch; it's called ALT Multifield. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/alt-multifield You can create a custom block of inputs and it all gets stored in one column. Hit me up if you have questions.

(I've actually got some significant improvements coming to it soon, but I can't guarantee a timeframe.)

Comment: If you feel like this completely answers your question, please consider accepting it as the Best Answer.

Comment: can you set which subfields are required?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately, but it's coming in the upcoming New & Improved version. :)